# How to retain the value once code enters into another function

Tags: c++, c, testing

I have a requirement in my `testing` as when I am calling a function I am initializing the structure with `0`. But, the moment function `ex()` gets called, `ab` the object of struct `abc` caontains garbage.
But I need to the structure abc should get initialized with `0`.

Because I don't have access to function `ex()`. So, whatever things I need to set, I need to set from `main()`.

```
struct abc{
    int a[4];
};
void ex()
{
abc ab;
    printf("%d\n", ab.a);//Garbage value
}
int main()
{
    abc ab;
    memset(&ab, 0, sizeof(abc));
    printf("%d\n", ab.a);
return 0;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Add a constructor that does whatever initialization you need.

Comment: `abc ab = {{0}};` does it.

Comment: You tagged C and C++, the answers are different for each, which one did you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give `abc` a default constructor that initializes the elements of the array to `0`. This gets rid of the garbage values:

```
struct abc {
    int a[4];
    abc() : a() {}
};
```

Next, if you want `myex` to print the data of the `abc` created in `main`, you should give it an `abc` reference parameter. This is a C++11 version of `myex`:

```
#include <iostream>

void myex(const abc& item)
{
  for (const auto& n : item.a)
  {
    std::cout << n << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  abc myabc;
  myex(myabc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ab` in `ex` is a different object from `ab` in `main`; initializing one doesn't affect the other.

If you intend for `ab` to refer to the same object in both `main` and `ex`, then you need to do one of the following:

- pass `ab` as an argument to `ex` from `main`;
- declare `ab` at file scope (outside of either `ex` or `main`);

Answer (score 1):

change the structure definition to following. That will take care

```
struct abc{
  int a[4];

  abc()
  { memset(a, 0, 4*sizeof(int)); }
};
```

Comment: No need for `memset`. Better to use an idiom that would work for user defined types too.

Comment: @paper.plane: I can not touch the code of `struct abc`. So, I can not change it's definition